# Is any possible way to get warning message through by oracle

Tags: oracle, java

I am working in developing oracle data base tool, I want display warning message when executing function. For example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FN_OEDS_CONVERTDATE2(
V_DATE DATE) RETURN VARCHAR2
    IS
BEGIN
DECLARE
    V_RETVALUE VARCHAR2(15) :='';
    BEGIN


    SELECT
        CASE V_DATE
            WHEN NULL THEN ''
            ELSE TO_CHAR(V_DATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY')
        END INTO V_RETVALUE FROM DUAL

     RETURN V_RETVALUE;
    END;

END;
/
```

Above function will execute successfully, but it wont through any error message , but it status would be invalid, how to get the warning message through by out in java.

Comment: In java i could able to get warning by st.getWarnings() , but display in general java.sql.SQLWarning: Warning: execution completed with warning , can i able to query and get exact oracle .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiler messages are not returned to the client through the getWarnings() on the statement or the connection.

Instead once you have identified the warning through `Statement.getWarnings()` you need to parse retrieve the compiler errors from the view `ALL_ERRORS`

Something like:

```
SELECT line, 
       position, 
       text, 
       name, 
       type 
FROM all_errors 
WHERE owner = user
AND type = 'FUNCTION'
AND name = 'FN_OEDS_CONVERTDATE2'
ORDER BY line, position
```